# 8-element permutations of a multiset {3:0,1:1,1:3,1:5,1:8,1:9} with the restriction 0 is not allowed in left or rightmost position

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins, multisets

I am lost in how to approach this problem due to the wording:

> Count the number of **distinct** 8-digit numbers that may be made by
>   **permuting the multi-set:**
>
> $$MS:=\{0:3,1:1,3:1,5:1,8:1,9:1\}$$
>
> **Given that $0$** **is not allowed in either the leftmost place or the rightmost place**

If possible, could someone please attempt this problem?

Counting, specifically balls-in-bins, is driving me crazy.

Comment: If you permute a multiset, you are allowed to use each element of the multiset as many times as it appears in the multiset.

Comment: Hi Phil, please be more detailed when giving the title to a question: details help other members to help you.

Comment: Taussig - is that true in all cases?

Comment: Tampieri - What details do you mean?

Comment: Yes, provided that you have an arrangement which allows you to use an element of the multiset as many times as it appears.  For instance, if we wanted to create two-element permutations of this multiset, we would only be permitted to use $0$ twice (dropping the restriction on the use of $0$ in this problem, of course).

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly an allowed eight-set permutation  of this multiset would be 10003589, but not 10000258?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to count the number of permutations of the multiset $0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9$ in which $0$ does not appear in the leftmost or rightmost position.

As stated in the comments, we may use each element in the multiset the number of times it appears in the multiset.  Two permutations are distinguishable if there is at least one position they do not have the same digit in that position.

**Strategy:**

1. Choose three of the middle six positions for the zeros.
2. Arrange the remaining five distinct numbers in the remaining five positions.

> We can choose three of the middle six positions for the zeros in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways and arrange the remaining five distinct numbers in the remaining five positions in $5!$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements of the multiset in which a zero does not occupy the leftmost or rightmost position is $$\binom{6}{3}5!$$

Comment: There are only six positions in the middle.  Once they have been filled, we have five distinct objects to place in five positions.  I have added a solution.  Hover over the shaded box to see it.